# Reputation display

Tags: support, reputation

Yesterday my reputation was 64 but when today is displaying 60 but not showing where my i lost my reputation!

I have tried to refresh page twice but no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the "show removed posts" tick at the bottom of the page. A couple old, closed questions with 0 or less net votes were removed, and suggested edit rep from the same was lost in the process:

[image]